# Visual Studio Code - Edit and Continue

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Iam using Visual Studio Code for developing NodeJS apps. Is there a way to make changes while the app is running (debugging) and see them without restarting the app ?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can use something like `nodemon` or `supervisor` to watch your files and restart app when you save changes

Answer (score 2):

I've requested for this feature and need more votes to get it accepted as valid request. You can vote too and wait with finger crossed.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/10336395-edit-and-continue-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Using VS 2013 with "Node.js-Tools for Visual Studio", changes in functions are applied in realtime. 
Furthermore this even works with remote-debugging from within Visual Studio. (Debugging->Attach to process->Node.js remote debugging)

Edit: Sorry, wasn't aware Visual Studio Code was a separate thing.